# Adding TFW metadata to TIFF header to create GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I'm aware this question has been asked several times already:
[Convert .tif with .tfw to a GeoTiff?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/convert-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff)
[tif tfw to GeoTiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103760/tif-tfw-to-geotiff)

However, my aim is a bit different here:
I have a few hundred TIFF files that have formerly been GeoTIFFs. I batch edited all of them in Photoshop so they lost their GeoTIFF header.

I'm still having the respective TFW file for each of them. Is there a way to re-attach the information from the TFW file to the TIFFs to create GeoTIFFs WITHOUT having to re-write all the GeoTIFFs again? (like GDAL does with gdal_translate -of GTiff input.tif ouput.tif).

I'm pretty sure I've seen a tool a few years ago that can simple re-attach the headers from the TFW files to Tiffs to create GeoTIFFs of them, I simply can't find it anymore.

Comment: There is a "geotifcp" program but it is making a new copy of the tiff as well. With gdal_edit.py https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html you can edit tiff in place but you must calculate the lower left corner coordinates for the option `-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry`. All information can be found from the .tfw.

Comment: Search on GeoTiff Examiner.  Here's a link: https://freegeographytools.com/2007/handling-tiff-worldfiles-with-geotiffexaminer

Answer (score 1):

If you have Avenza's [Geographic Imager](https://www.avenza.com/geographic-imager/) you can script exporting georeferencing from Photoshop right into the TIFFs w/o re-writing them. In fact, you wouldn't actually have to re-export them to begin with, because they all the geospatial information would be autoamtically maintained when the files are saved in Photoshop.
I believe this functionality is supported even the basic version, for GeoTIFFs

Answer (score -2):

If it's possible, you can use QGIS. In raster menu you will find Projection, under it feature Assign Projection. You can use batch processing and process all your tiff at once.