# TIFFs with Worldfiles to GeoTIFFs

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I'm looking for a way to convert several TIFFs with Worldfiles to GeoTIFFs.
Is there an option using ArcGIS or Python (Arcpy)? What is the best option you could recommend?

Comment: Most "What is the best" questions are not a good fit for the GIS SE "focused question / best answer" model.  The [Don't Ask](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page sets a high bar for fundamentally subjective questions, which would require a great deal of research and wordsmithing (far more effort than Export... Raster to Different Format, or downloading libgeotiff. or installing GDAL)

Comment: @Vince this is a very specific ArcGIS question, no research is required. Every question with "best" doesn't need to set off an alarm.

Comment: Caution: I've had strange bugs in the past where the root cause turned out to be Geotiffs with world files where the registration in the geotiff header conflicted with what was in the world file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ArcMap, Conversion Tools, Raster Toolset, Raster to other format? choose tif as the output. Also, I remember from ArcMap, table of contents, you can export an Image, tweak the settings. It seems ArcGIS prefers to create a Geotiff instead of tif/world file. Also with Geotiff you can assign a spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to georeference the images with ArcGIS or QGIS in order to avoid distortions. If you save the outcome a world file will automatically produced next to the corrected TIFF image

Comment: the tiff files are already georeferenced since they have a worldfile, i would like to change the tif (with the worldfile) to a GEOTIFF using ArcMap. Is there a tool or function available?

Comment: In that case you could stick to the explanations given here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/how-to-convert-a-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff