# How to change geotiff file using the header?

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I have some geotiff file and I need to change the position: 500 meters to east and 500 m to south. Resolution is 12,5 meters.

I've tried using GeoTIFF Tools GUI, and I've created .gtf file, but I don't know what I should write in.

Also I've tried with GeoTiffExaminer, but after I wrote in X vector X and Y vector Y values nothing changes.

Comment: Do you mean you want to leave the imagery untouched and just update its _embedded_ geographic reference? If so, this will allow you to do so: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87663/51035

Answer (score 4):

You can use gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html with the "assign upper-left lower-right" option

```
-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry:
    Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file. This assigns georeferenced bounds to the output file, ignoring what would have been derived from the source file. So this does not cause reprojection to the specified SRS.
```

Gdal_translate will make a copy of the image. If you prefer to update in place, use gdal_edit.py http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html with the same option

```
-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry:

    Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the dataset.
```