# Exporting GeoTIFFs from QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I would like to export my map as a GeoTIFF in QGIS. My workflow is as follows: Project - Import/export - export map to image…

I have two questions about this: instead of saving the image as a GeoTIFF, QGIS saves it as a normal TIFF file and a world-file. How can I export it as a single GeoTIFF?

Also, when I re-import the image into QGIS, it returns the error message that the coordinate system is not defined. How can I export the image correctly with the coordinate system, which I had put for the map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a .tif with .tfw to a GeoTiff?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/how-to-convert-a-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff)

Comment: I fear this is a missing feature in Export to map image. You can fix it by post-processing with gdal `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:xxxx input.tif output_geo.tif`where xxxx in epsg:xxxx is the projection code that you probably know. Or  use gdal_edit.py and attach the coordinate system in place without creating a copy of the image.

Comment: Hi user30184, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried it and indeed managed to get a geotiff. However, the problem about QGIS complaining that the coordinate system is not defined persists… Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: As a fairly new user,  please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question.

Answer (score 0):

While exporting you have to tick the box to generate the georreferencing file (as you can see in the picture). This will generate a tiff file and a .tfw file. The TFW is the file which contains the geographic parameters to open the image correctly in QGIS (try opening the TFW with notepad and you'll see what I mean).

[image]

Comment: Hi Guillermo, thanks for your response. It does not quite answer my question though. I want to have a single geotiff file in the end and also am having problems with the coordinate system (see above). I don't quite see how your answer relates to either of these problems.

Comment: You are welcome! I've tried deleting the auxiliary files, keeping only the tiff, and QGIS loaded it properly placed, without any georreferencing issues. Also you can re-export it with QGIS (no need of using "proccesing"). It worked for me on QGIS 3.2