# Convert Mars TIFF file on simple cyllindrical projection to a GeoTIFF

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, mapbox

I have rendered a TIFF file, which is on the Mars2000, simple cyllindrical projection format.
I want to upload the file to MapBox, and thus need a GeoTiff file.

How can I use GDAL, or similar, to convert the TIFF file to a GeoTIFF?

The image is on the exact same format and resolution as [Mars MGS MOLA](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Mars/GlobalSurveyor/MOLA/Mars_MGS_MOLA_DEM_mosaic_global_463m/cub), as this was the base image for the render, which looks like this: [image: Mars Render]

I used GDAL with the command `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs .\format.wkt input.tif output.tif` (which worked without errors) however when I upload to MapBox I get the following error `Error creating Mapnik Datasource: could not read georeferencing`  , so I suspect the format is still corrupt somehow.

Comment: what is the disk file size of the TIFF, have you tried using this online converter? https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/img-to-geotiff

Comment: @Yogi It's 4GB, so that might be an option. If I understood their pricing correctly I would have to purchase a premium plan though.

Comment: It's free for the first few conversions though. But not sure if the browser limit will allow you to get it uploaded. Give it a try.

Comment: It's only free for 5 MB, I would have to purchase the most expensive plan to convert all 4GB unfortunately

Comment: oops! then might have to see other options. There are other ways around it besides making it too expensive. Do you have any GIS desktop apps?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/convert-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956818/how-to-use-gdal-to-create-geotiff-from-tiff-and-4-corners-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Yes, I have ArcGIS Pro. I'll try the GDAL solution, however I'm unsure of what to specify in the coordinate system argument as the mars2000 format is not very common

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question body, it would be more useful to create an an answer and accept it as correct.

Comment: @Matt Noted. Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to do an inspection of the original TIFF (using `gdalinfo`) to figure out the corner coordinates of the projection, and copying the projection format to a file named `format.wkt`. The correct metadata was then assigned using `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs .\format.wkt -a_ullr -10669675.197 5334837.599 10669675.197 -5334837.599 input.tif output.tif`